# Is there any way to use off screen render with Rust

Tags: opengl, rust, glut, egl

I am now working on a GPU-render project with Rust and OpenGL (more accurately, with glium ) and now the rendered picture is shown on the screen.

But the next step is to distribute this program on a linux server with an Nvidia GPU but without X-server. I have learned from https://devblogs.nvidia.com/egl-eye-opengl-visualization-without-x-server/ that `EGL` can be used for off-screen render, and I have notice that `glutin` crate contains `EGL` binding, such as `glutin_egl_sys`; but I can not find the function `eglGetDisplay()`.

So I wonder is there any way to use off screen render with Rust, or must I use `EGL` raw bindings?

Comment: I think you want to search for "glutin headless context". You need to create an OpenGL context without opening a window. That's what headless contexts do. Try replacing `build_windowed` with [`build_headless`](https://docs.rs/glutin/0.21.0/glutin/struct.ContextBuilder.html#method.build_headless).

Comment: thank you.hmm...but now, I find the `build_headless` method returns `Context<NotCurrent>` and I use `glium::backend::glutin::headless::Headless` as `Facade` to replace `glium::Display` and the output is nothing... what happened?

Comment: What do you mean "the output is nothing"? How do you observe the output if not via a window? But it seems like you want to make a [MVCE] out of this problem and ask another question on this site!

Comment: hmm...right, I'm going to ask another question